# Owl Identification. Winter in Haliburton, Ontario, Canada

Tags: owls

Can anyone help me identify this owl. Is it a 'Great Grey Owl' or 'Barred Owl'. I'm thinking a Great Grey because it was quite huge - about 1.5 to 2 feet tall? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Owl in snow-covered tree]

Comment: Beautiful photo.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/106634/15950)

Answer (score 6):

Caveat:I'm no expert, or even from North America

I think this is the Barred Owl (*[Strix varia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barred_owl)*). The reason I say this is because it has the strongly barred pattern to the feathers on the wings, and a pale striped belly, and lacks the white "collar" (mustache) below the beak.

The Great Grey Owl (*[Strix nebulosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_grey_owl)*), in contrast, has a less distinct pattern on the wings, is generally a darker grey colour and has a white collar under the beak.

The Barred and Great Grey overlap in size (sizes from Wikipedia), with the lower end of the Grey (24-33 in/61-84 cm) being similar to the upper end of the Barred (16-25 in/40-63 cm). So yours would be small for a Great Grey, but average/large for Barred.

Comment: And, barred are relatively common.

Comment: Also, the Great Grey seems to have strikingly yellow eyes (search Google images), while the Barred Owl has dark/brown eyes matching the image above.

Comment: I am an expert AND from North America, and I agree this is a barred owl. The eyes and face shape are the giveaways. Great grays are rare, and typically only found around meadows or forest openings, and are strictly active at night. Barred owls are common,  found in more forested habitats, with closed canopies, and are active around dusk and dawn, but sometimes hunt in the day time. Great photo!

Answer (score 1):

Eye color is often the best feature to use as a starting point with owl species that are similar to each other. It can often eliminate some possibilities immediately. Your owl is a barred owl. Great gray has light-colored eyes. Barred has dark eyes. Other features are useful, but the difference between them can be determined by eyes alone.

The Owl research Institute has an excellent owl ID resource for North American owls at https://www.owlresearchinstitute.org/species-id-guide.

That's an excellent photo. Thank you for sharing it.